# How to make buttons in all the rows same size in Android?

Tags: android-layout, button

I have created a row of buttons dynamically but one of the buttons has a little more text. The buttons in that row are having the same size as the button containing more text but these row of buttons are larger than the other buttons in the other rows. The following is my code:

```
 LinearLayout dynamicview = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttons);

     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                Button btnTag = new Button(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);

                btnTag.setLayoutParams(param);
                Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                int width=display.getWidth();

                btnTag.setText("" + (j + 1 + (i * 5)));
                btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 5));
                btnTag.setWidth(width/5);


                if(btnTag.getId() == 13) {

                    btnTag.setText("has more txt");

                }
                if(btnTag.getId() == 14) {
                    btnTag.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                if(btnTag.getId() == 15) {
                    btnTag.setText("C");
                }
                row.addView(btnTag);

            }

            dynamicview.addView(row);
}
```

where R.id.buttons in the XML is:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

Could you please let me know if there is any way in which I can make all 3 rows of buttons have the same width and height?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

setGravity(..) 'center' should work. You can also try the column stretch mode. Your code is a little confusing because it looks like it is doing more than it should.

I will wait for your answer before simulating it in my  machine and post you the code